# Trick Windows To See Second Monitor

Tags: c#, c++, c, winapi, language-agnostic

is there anyway to trick windows into thinking that a second monitor is connected to the computer, even if there isnt one?

Example:

Laptop also has an external screen connected into it. The external screen is the primary screen.

When the screen is disconnected the laptop becomes primary even if the external screen is reconnected. Is there a way to trick windows into thinking that the monitor is always there? and not revert to the laptop screen as primary screen?

The way I am thinking it could work is some kind of low level driver? But I wouldnt have a clue where to start

Comment: Might belong on superuser, but it can be likened to a programming topic. I don't think the OP is looking for a 1-click solution, i think he wants to program it?

Comment: It is a programmer question, but which so far has no practical programming answer.  I imagine it could be solved with a custom or patched Windows graphics driver though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For work, I actually had the same situation -- on an embedded PC, we needed a second monitor to always be available.

I put a considerable amount of time into researching it, but I wasn't able to find any solution other than with hardware.

If you have a VGA port (or DVI-I), you're in luck.  You can find directions on how to fake that with a couple resistors ([here's one set of directions](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-help-here/applications/430465-vnc-without-monitor-connected.html)).

Ultimately, for my project, we only had a DVI-D port available.  I had to come up with a microcontroller solution to send "fake" monitor signals (via I2C) to the PC.  I can't go into much more specific detail than that, unfortunately.

Comment: For VGA (from your link in case it dies):Connect 75 ohm resistor from pin 1 to pin 6,
 Connect 75 ohm resistor from pin 2 to pin 7
 Connect 75 ohm resistor from pin 3 to pin 8

Comment: is there any way to do this or similar for a hdmi connection? or is tricking the hdcp link not possible?